# How to load spherical panorama image tile

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

We have a web application which loads a spherical panorama. This application is developed using Three.js. Texture is a 360 degree image. As the image size becomes big the loading is slow. We would like how this can be over come by tiling the images into small pieces and load the tiles of the visible part only.
Appreciate your help!

Answer (score -1):

Usually 360 panoramic images are loaded in as cube-maps, so something like http://www.humus.name/Textures/SaintPetersSquare1.jpg

You can split the cubemap up into many images, as is done in most THREE.js examples

http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_cubemap

```
var path = "textures/cube/SwedishRoyalCastle/";
var format = '.jpg';
var urls = [
    path + 'px' + format, path + 'nx' + format,
    path + 'py' + format, path + 'ny' + format,
    path + 'pz' + format, path + 'nz' + format
  ];

var reflectionCube = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube( urls );
reflectionCube.format = THREE.RGBFormat;

var refractionCube = new THREE.CubeTexture( reflectionCube.image, THREE.CubeRefractionMapping );
refractionCube.format = THREE.RGBFormat;
```

To make your image loading more bearable, add an event to the image loading, using the ImageLoader and LoadManager:

[ImageLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/loaders/ImageLoader)

Comment: Thank you Flux. We are not using cube. We use sphere and loading texture from a single image. could you just spread some more light on "You can split the cubemap up into many images, as is done in most THREE.js examples". Where we don't have to split the image.

Comment: Well, even if your source image is a 360 degree sphere, the texture is still going to be a square, or many squares. See http://aerotwist.com/tutorials/create-your-own-environment-maps/

Comment: Appreciate this; but our real issue is how we can load the area (around FOV) and display this to user rather than user waiting for the whole panorama texture to be loaded. Here is where we thought of tiling the image as is done by google street view.

Comment: Found any solution yet? I'm stuck on the same issue with tiling. One picture is working, but adding zoom with more tiles seems to be quite difficult.